# Updating redux slice with multiple values

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I am using a redux slice in a react project to store information about the current user. However, I am getting the following error when loading the page:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
```

Dashboard.js:

```
export function Dashboard() {
const currentUser = useSelector(state => state.currentUser);
const dispatch = useDispatch();

return (
   <div>
      <p>{currentUser.name}</p>
      <p>{currentUser.description}</p>
   </div>
   <Button onClick={() => dispatch(setCurrentUser(name, description))}>Set user</Button>
);
}
```

currentUserSlice.js:

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

export const currentUser = createSlice({
  name: 'currentUser',
  initialState: {
    name: "",
    description: ""
  },
  reducers: {
    setCurrentUser: (state, action) => {
        return state =  {
            name: action.payload.name,
            description: action.payload.description
        }
    }
  }
})

// each case under reducers becomes an action
export const { setCurrentUser } = currentUserSlice.actions

export default currentUserSlice.reducer
```

store.js:

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

import currentUserReducer from './currentUserSlice'

export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    currentUser: currentUserReducer,
  }
})
```

**Update**
I did not properly import the reducer into store.js. However, the dispatch is not updating the data now that I have imported it

Comment: Can you show your store.js file ?

Comment: @BENARDPatrick thanks for the quick reply. I updated the store.js file, however the data is not being updated on dispatch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending two values in your payload instead of an object. Please update your dispatched function to send an object instead:

```
export function Dashboard() {
const currentUser = useSelector(state => state.currentUser);
const dispatch = useDispatch();

return (
   <div>
      <p>{currentUser.name}</p>
      <p>{currentUser.description}</p>
   </div>
   <Button onClick={() => dispatch(setCurrentUser({name, description}))}>Set user</Button>
);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Since I am passing them in an object do I have to change the way I am accessing them in the reducer?

Comment: No it should stay the way you've done it, give it a try

Comment: I tested it out a different way before you replied. The way to access them was by replacing "action" in the arguments with {payload} and then accessing each value by payload.value. Please update your answer for future reference

Comment: It is actually the same thing, action object has two properties, type, and payload. You can decide to restructure them or you may just use action.payload.name for example.